# Swagger-UI: Protect Swagger-UI access

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using a locally hosted [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) on top of `Node` on an `EC2` `Ubuntu` instance.

Currently, in a browser when I type `localhost:3000/myproject`, I get the rendering, which basically pulls: `http://localhost:3000/api-docs.json`

I would like to protect `myproject` and `api-docs.json` so not everyone on the web can access them and nor can Google index them.

Ideally it would nice to add `ssh` `keys` so only the hosts that have the `key` can access the Swagger UI.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I am having a similar issue. If you have figured out a way, could you answer you question?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Nope.  Sorry.  I stopped checking it into my repo and moved it to Confluence.  Two step process, but not sure what else to do.